# Python3 Function return value

Tags: python-3.x

I believe I have something incorrect with my function but I still pretty new to python and functions in general and I am missing what my issue is.  In the code below I am sending no values into the function, but once the function reads the database I want it to pull the values from the database back into the main program.  I placed a print statement inside of the function to make sure its pulling the values from the database and everything works properly.  I copy and pasted that same print line right after the function call in the main area but I am getting a `NameError: 'wins' is not defined`.  This leads me to believe I am not returning the values correctly?

```
#Python3
import pymysql

def read_db():
    db = pymysql.connect(host='**********',user='**********',password='**********',db='**********')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM loot WHERE id = 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        wins = row[2]
        skips = row[3]
        lumber1 = row[4]
        ore1 = row[5]
        mercury1 = row[6]
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    print ("Wins = ",wins," Skips = ",skips," Lumber = ",lumber1," Ore = ",ore1," Mercury = ",mercury1)
    return (wins, skips, lumber1, ore1, mercury1)

read_db()
print ("Wins = ",wins," Skips = ",skips," Lumber = ",lumber1," Ore = ",ore1," Mercury = ",mercury1)
```

Comment: Variables declared in a function (or class) do not exist outside the function (or class). This is so you can use the same name for different variables doing different things in different contexts, and they won’t interfere with each other. You also don’t need to care about the variable names used in functions you call. This is called “lexical scope”, it’s very useful, and all modern languages use it (though it took surprisingly long to invent). However, this means that, as others point out, you need to assign names to the return values of functions if you want to use them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing just `read_db()` causes the return values to be thrown out. You need to assign the return values to variables:

```
wins, skips, lumber, ore = read_db()
```

The fact that you're returning a variable called `wins` does not mean a `wins` variable will become available in the scope you call `read_db()` from. You need to assign return values explicitly.